# How to check whether the dymo label printer drivers are installed in web application browser or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, web, dymo

How to Check weather dymo labels drivers are installed in a machine or not using dymolabel javascript API for web browser.

Is there any way by which we can get this information using javascript/ jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is probably impossible. Web browsers do not provide web pages with access to this sort of information (unless the printer drivers are browser plugins).

Comment: Is there any condition to check with the browser.

Comment: No, since the browser will not tell web pages what drivers are installed. You will need to ask the user instead, unfortunately.